# Rails update method for updating records not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mongoid

I have two methods in **PersonsController**- edit and update and a **Person** model:

```
def edit
  @person=Person.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @person=Person.find(params[:id])
    @person.update_attributes(params[:person])
end
```

and my **edit.html.erb**:

```
<h2> Edit info here!</h2>
<%= @person.name %>

<%= form_for @person, html: {mulitpart: true}  do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field :location %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit :submit , class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %></p>
<% end %>
```

and routes.rb:

> resources :persons

But when I submit the form I get:

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound
>   The action '5231d2491dba7fb057000004' could not be found for PersonsController

The 5231....... is id of a person.

Request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"3TL7nn4UxhxFoxETeooBMThhkE0VdMoGFpjN9sx4srk=", "person"=>{"location"=>"nagpur"}, "commit"=>"submit", "controller"=>"persons", "action"=>"5231d2491dba7fb057000004"}
```

What is wrong here? I'm using mongoid and rails 3.2.13.

Comment: please show routes for persons.

Comment: @BillyChan I have `resources :persons` in routes. But I don't think that's required for a **Person** model. Routes are for controllers only(?)

Comment: I doubt how comes `params[:name]` because if everything as convention there is no such param except `params[:id]`.

Comment: @BillyChan I have a fields `name` and `location` for my Person's model

Comment: I know, but that's only model method. How come it becomes a param?

Comment: @BillyChan I'm not getting you.Sorry, I'm new to rails.That `params[:name]` work well in the edit action. I'm passing the `name` from the form's `hidden_field`. What would you suggest otherwise?

Comment: Looks fine, not sure the reason. Maybe the cache issue, try manually remove cache in browser, and cache in /tmp, restart server.

Comment: i don't think that's cache issue. Tried everything possible. But the error thrown in also wierd. Thanks for help. @BillyChan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final comment reveals the source of error.

For either `#edit` or `#update`, you should not set the params manually in hidden field, which is also unnecessary.

If using conventional RESTful routes as `resources :persons`, you edit route will look like `GET /persons/1/edit` where `1` is the param `id`. You can get this person in `#edit` as

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
```

Similarly, you can get the person again in #update whose route is `PUT persons/1`

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
```

Then the question is answered.

But there is one more problem in your code, the part you get the attributes for updating. Because the params of person's attributes are sent via form, all attributes are under `params[:person]`. Thus, to get the photo attribute, you should use

```
params[:person][:photo] # Not params[:photo]
```

Comment: Still it cannot find person with the id in the update method. Gives **Calling Document.find with nil is invalid.** I would like to add is that I don't have any **PersonsController**

Comment: Remove the `url: {...}` part in form, it's unnecessary.

Comment: That may be the reason no param conveyed, so remove it.

Comment: Can't. As I said I don't have a **PersonsController**. otherwise @person searches for a PersonsController and Gives **uninitialized constant PersonsController** (tried this)

Comment: I think why that is working with #edit is because the link which directs to edit page, I'm passing person's id as a parameter. But we aren't passing any parameter for the #update. May be I'm wrong!

Comment: hmmm, `resources :persons` but no persons controller, not nice at all. Anyway, fire your `rake routes` to check the path name for updating a person, use that route with person as argument, like `url: managedb_path(@person)`.

Comment: Updated the question. I have added the **PersonsController** now.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question, neither route. It's the form's error. Try remove `:submit` in submit line, to read `f.submit "Submit", class: {blah blah}`